# How to further optimize the query after adding composite indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

| province_id | owner_id | game_id | resource_production | valid_from | valid_until | static_province_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| auto incremented Integer | integer | integer | integer | timestamp | timestamp | integer |

I have two indexes:

- test_valid_from(game_id, owner_id, valid_from, valid_until)
- test_valid_until(game_id, owner_id, valid_until, valid_from)

Every time the production of a province changes the valid_until timestamp of the old provinces gets set to the current timestamp. Also a new province is inserted with the current timestamp in the valid_from field. If the province is the newest province of its static_province_id in this game valid_until is null.

## My Goal

I want to have a sub 1 second query that can get me the total resource production for every change in resource production of an owner in a specified game.

## My first approach

### 1. Query

```sql
SELECT
    a.game_id,
    a.valid_from,
    a.owner_id,
    SUM(b.resource_production)
FROM
    (select distinct valid_from, owner_id, game_id from province) a
    JOIN province b
    ON  a.game_id = b.game_id
        AND a.owner_id = b.owner_id
        AND ( 
            (
                b.valid_from < a.valid_from 
                and a.valid_from < b.valid_until 
            )
            OR a.valid_from = b.valid_from
            OR (
                b.valid_until IS NULL
                AND b.valid_from < a.valid_from))
where a.game_id=1 and a.owner_id = 1
GROUP BY a.game_id, a.owner_id, a.valid_from
```

### Explain

```json
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "1773449.97"
    },
    "grouping_operation": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "using_filesort": false,
      "nested_loop": [
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "a",
            "access_type": "ALL",
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 20940,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 20940,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "264.25",
              "eval_cost": "2094.00",
              "prefix_cost": "2358.25",
              "data_read_per_join": "490K"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "valid_from",
              "owner_id",
              "game_id"
            ],
            "materialized_from_subquery": {
              "using_temporary_table": true,
              "dependent": false,
              "cacheable": true,
              "query_block": {
                "select_id": 2,
                "cost_info": {
                  "query_cost": "2189.32"
                },
                "duplicates_removal": {
                  "using_filesort": false,
                  "table": {
                    "table_name": "province",
                    "access_type": "ref",
                    "possible_keys": [
                      "ix_gid_plid_vf_vl",
                      "test_valid_until",
                      "test_valid_from"
                    ],
                    "key": "test_valid_from",
                    "used_key_parts": [
                      "game_id",
                      "owner_id"
                    ],
                    "key_length": "12",
                    "ref": [
                      "const",
                      "const"
                    ],
                    "rows_examined_per_scan": 20940,
                    "rows_produced_per_join": 20940,
                    "filtered": "100.00",
                    "using_index": true,
                    "cost_info": {
                      "read_cost": "95.32",
                      "eval_cost": "2094.00",
                      "prefix_cost": "2189.32",
                      "data_read_per_join": "1M"
                    },
                    "used_columns": [
                      "province_id",
                      "owner_id",
                      "valid_from",
                      "game_id",
                      "static_province_id"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "b",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "ix_gid_plid_vf_vl",
              "test_valid_until",
              "test_valid_from"
            ],
            "key": "test_valid_until",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "game_id",
              "owner_id"
            ],
            "key_length": "12",
            "ref": [
              "a.game_id",
              "a.owner_id"
            ],
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 241,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 1146881,
            "filtered": "22.66",
            "index_condition": "(((`testing`.`b`.`valid_from` < `a`.`valid_from`) and (`a`.`valid_from` < `testing`.`b`.`valid_until`)) or (`testing`.`b`.`valid_from` = `a`.`valid_from`) or ((`testing`.`b`.`valid_until` is null) and (`testing`.`b`.`valid_from` < `a`.`valid_from`)))",
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "1265065.52",
              "eval_cost": "114688.15",
              "prefix_cost": "1773449.97",
              "data_read_per_join": "70M"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "province_id",
              "owner_id",
              "resource_production",
              "valid_from",
              "valid_until",
              "game_id",
              "static_province_id"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Result

| game_id | valid_from | owner_id | SUM(b.resource_production) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2022-10-25 23:02:13' | 1 | 7829 |
| 1 | '2022-10-26 00:22:14' | 1 | 7836 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

The query works, but it is way to slow as it takes about 17 seconds.

## My second approach

i have read that the mysql optimizer might not use the index in multiple or conditions as it is the case in my first query with the valid_from and valid_until.

### 2.Query

```sql
select g.game_id, g.owner_id, g.valid_from, sum(g.rp) from (
    select a_b.game_id, a_b.owner_id, a.resource_production as rp, a_b.valid_from from(select distinct valid_from, owner_id, game_id from province) a_b
    join province a
    on a.game_id = a_b.game_id
            AND a.owner_id = a_b.owner_id
            AND 
                (
                    a.valid_from < a_b.valid_from 
                    and a_b.valid_from < a.valid_until 
                )
    Union
    select b_b.game_id, b_b.owner_id, b.resource_production as rp, b_b.valid_from from(select distinct valid_from, owner_id, game_id from province) b_b
    join province b
    on b.game_id = b_b.game_id
            AND b.owner_id = b_b.owner_id
            AND b.valid_from = b_b.valid_from 
    Union
    select c_b.game_id, c_b.owner_id, c.resource_production as rp, c_b.valid_from from(select distinct valid_from, owner_id, game_id from province) c_b
    join province c
    on c.game_id = c_b.game_id
            AND c.owner_id = c_b.owner_id
            AND (
                c.valid_until IS NULL
                AND c_b.valid_from < c.valid_from )) g
where g.game_id=1 and g.owner_id=1
group by g.game_id, g.owner_id, g.valid_from
```

### Explain

```json
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "76805.35"
    },
    "grouping_operation": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "g",
        "access_type": "ALL",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 682692,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 682692,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "8536.15",
          "eval_cost": "68269.20",
          "prefix_cost": "76805.35",
          "data_read_per_join": "20M"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "game_id",
          "owner_id",
          "rp",
          "valid_from"
        ],
        "materialized_from_subquery": {
          "using_temporary_table": true,
          "dependent": false,
          "cacheable": true,
          "query_block": {
            "union_result": {
              "using_temporary_table": true,
              "select_id": 8,
              "table_name": "<union2,4,6>",
              "access_type": "ALL",
              "query_specifications": [
                {
                  "dependent": false,
                  "cacheable": true,
                  "query_block": {
                    "select_id": 2,
                    "cost_info": {
                      "query_cost": "1773449.97"
                    },
                    "nested_loop": [
                      {
                        "table": {
                          "table_name": "a_b",
                          "access_type": "ALL",
                          "rows_examined_per_scan": 20940,
                          "rows_produced_per_join": 20940,
                          "filtered": "100.00",
                          "cost_info": {
                            "read_cost": "264.25",
                            "eval_cost": "2094.00",
                            "prefix_cost": "2358.25",
                            "data_read_per_join": "490K"
                          },
                          "used_columns": [
                            "valid_from",
                            "owner_id",
                            "game_id"
                          ],
                          "materialized_from_subquery": {
                            "using_temporary_table": true,
                            "dependent": false,
                            "cacheable": true,
                            "query_block": {
                              "select_id": 3,
                              "cost_info": {
                                "query_cost": "2189.32"
                              },
                              "duplicates_removal": {
                                "using_filesort": false,
                                "table": {
                                  "table_name": "province",
                                  "access_type": "ref",
                                  "possible_keys": [
                                    "ix_gid_plid_vf_vl",
                                    "test_valid_until",
                                    "test_valid_from"
                                  ],
                                  "key": "test_valid_from",
                                  "used_key_parts": [
                                    "game_id",
                                    "owner_id"
                                  ],
                                  "key_length": "12",
                                  "ref": [
                                    "const",
                                    "const"
                                  ],
                                  "rows_examined_per_scan": 20940,
                                  "rows_produced_per_join": 20940,
                                  "filtered": "100.00",
                                  "using_index": true,
                                  "cost_info": {
                                    "read_cost": "95.32",
                                    "eval_cost": "2094.00",
                                    "prefix_cost": "2189.32",
                                    "data_read_per_join": "1M"
                                  },
                                  "used_columns": [
                                    "province_id",
                                    "owner_id",
                                    "valid_from",
                                    "game_id",
                                    "static_province_id"
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "table": {
                          "table_name": "a",
                          "access_type": "ref",
                          "possible_keys": [
                            "ix_gid_plid_vf_vl",
                            "test_valid_until",
                            "test_valid_from"
                          ],
                          "key": "test_valid_until",
                          "used_key_parts": [
                            "game_id",
                            "owner_id"
                          ],
                          "key_length": "12",
                          "ref": [
                            "a_b.game_id",
                            "a_b.owner_id"
                          ],
                          "rows_examined_per_scan": 241,
                          "rows_produced_per_join": 562138,
                          "filtered": "11.11",
                          "index_condition": "((`testing`.`a`.`valid_from` < `a_b`.`valid_from`) and (`a_b`.`valid_from` < `testing`.`a`.`valid_until`))",
                          "cost_info": {
                            "read_cost": "1265065.52",
                            "eval_cost": "56213.89",
                            "prefix_cost": "1773449.97",
                            "data_read_per_join": "34M"
                          },
                          "used_columns": [
                            "owner_id",
                            "resource_production",
                            "valid_from",
                            "valid_until",
                            "game_id"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "dependent": false,
                  "cacheable": true,
                  "query_block": {
                    "select_id": 4,
                    "cost_info": {
                      "query_cost": "33802.62"
                    },
                    "nested_loop": [
                      {
                        "table": {
                          "table_name": "b_b",
                          "access_type": "ALL",
                          "rows_examined_per_scan": 20940,
                          "rows_produced_per_join": 20940,
                          "filtered": "100.00",
                          "cost_info": {
                            "read_cost": "264.25",
                            "eval_cost": "2094.00",
                            "prefix_cost": "2358.25",
                            "data_read_per_join": "490K"
                          },
                          "used_columns": [
                            "valid_from",
                            "owner_id",
                            "game_id"
                          ],
                          "materialized_from_subquery": {
                            "using_temporary_table": true,
                            "dependent": false,
                            "cacheable": true,
                            "query_block": {
                              "select_id": 5,
                              "cost_info": {
                                "query_cost": "2189.32"
                              },
                              "duplicates_removal": {
                                "using_filesort": false,
                                "table": {
                                  "table_name": "province",
                                  "access_type": "ref",
                                  "possible_keys": [
                                    "ix_gid_plid_vf_vl",
                                    "test_valid_until",
                                    "test_valid_from"
                                  ],
                                  "key": "test_valid_from",
                                  "used_key_parts": [
                                    "game_id",
                                    "owner_id"
                                  ],
                                  "key_length": "12",
                                  "ref": [
                                    "const",
                                    "const"
                                  ],
                                  "rows_examined_per_scan": 20940,
                                  "rows_produced_per_join": 20940,
                                  "filtered": "100.00",
                                  "using_index": true,
                                  "cost_info": {
                                    "read_cost": "95.32",
                                    "eval_cost": "2094.00",
                                    "prefix_cost": "2189.32",
                                    "data_read_per_join": "1M"
                                  },
                                  "used_columns": [
                                    "province_id",
                                    "owner_id",
                                    "valid_from",
                                    "game_id",
                                    "static_province_id"
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "table": {
                          "table_name": "b",
                          "access_type": "ref",
                          "possible_keys": [
                            "ix_gid_plid_vf_vl",
                            "test_valid_until",
                            "test_valid_from"
                          ],
                          "key": "test_valid_from",
                          "used_key_parts": [
                            "game_id",
                            "owner_id",
                            "valid_from"
                          ],
                          "key_length": "16",
                          "ref": [
                            "b_b.game_id",
                            "b_b.owner_id",
                            "b_b.valid_from"
                          ],
                          "rows_examined_per_scan": 4,
                          "rows_produced_per_join": 89841,
                          "filtered": "100.00",
                          "cost_info": {
                            "read_cost": "22460.27",
                            "eval_cost": "8984.11",
                            "prefix_cost": "33802.62",
                            "data_read_per_join": "5M"
                          },
                          "used_columns": [
                            "owner_id",
                            "resource_production",
                            "valid_from",
                            "game_id"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "dependent": false,
                  "cacheable": true,
                  "query_block": {
                    "select_id": 6,
                    "cost_info": {
                      "query_cost": "34611.03"
                    },
                    "nested_loop": [
                      {
                        "table": {
                          "table_name": "c_b",
                          "access_type": "ALL",
                          "rows_examined_per_scan": 20940,
                          "rows_produced_per_join": 20940,
                          "filtered": "100.00",
                          "cost_info": {
                            "read_cost": "264.25",
                            "eval_cost": "2094.00",
                            "prefix_cost": "2358.25",
                            "data_read_per_join": "490K"
                          },
                          "used_columns": [
                            "valid_from",
                            "owner_id",
                            "game_id"
                          ],
                          "materialized_from_subquery": {
                            "using_temporary_table": true,
                            "dependent": false,
                            "cacheable": true,
                            "query_block": {
                              "select_id": 7,
                              "cost_info": {
                                "query_cost": "2189.32"
                              },
                              "duplicates_removal": {
                                "using_filesort": false,
                                "table": {
                                  "table_name": "province",
                                  "access_type": "ref",
                                  "possible_keys": [
                                    "ix_gid_plid_vf_vl",
                                    "test_valid_until",
                                    "test_valid_from"
                                  ],
                                  "key": "test_valid_from",
                                  "used_key_parts": [
                                    "game_id",
                                    "owner_id"
                                  ],
                                  "key_length": "12",
                                  "ref": [
                                    "const",
                                    "const"
                                  ],
                                  "rows_examined_per_scan": 20940,
                                  "rows_produced_per_join": 20940,
                                  "filtered": "100.00",
                                  "using_index": true,
                                  "cost_info": {
                                    "read_cost": "95.32",
                                    "eval_cost": "2094.00",
                                    "prefix_cost": "2189.32",
                                    "data_read_per_join": "1M"
                                  },
                                  "used_columns": [
                                    "province_id",
                                    "owner_id",
                                    "valid_from",
                                    "game_id",
                                    "static_province_id"
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "table": {
                          "table_name": "c",
                          "access_type": "ref",
                          "possible_keys": [
                            "ix_gid_plid_vf_vl",
                            "test_valid_until",
                            "test_valid_from"
                          ],
                          "key": "test_valid_until",
                          "used_key_parts": [
                            "game_id",
                            "owner_id",
                            "valid_until"
                          ],
                          "key_length": "17",
                          "ref": [
                            "c_b.game_id",
                            "c_b.owner_id",
                            "const"
                          ],
                          "rows_examined_per_scan": 4,
                          "rows_produced_per_join": 30713,
                          "filtered": "33.33",
                          "index_condition": "((`testing`.`c`.`valid_until` is null) and (`c_b`.`valid_from` < `testing`.`c`.`valid_from`))",
                          "cost_info": {
                            "read_cost": "23037.70",
                            "eval_cost": "3071.39",
                            "prefix_cost": "34611.03",
                            "data_read_per_join": "1M"
                          },
                          "used_columns": [
                            "owner_id",
                            "resource_production",
                            "valid_from",
                            "valid_until",
                            "game_id"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Result

| game_id | owner_id | valid_from | sum(g.rp) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | '2022-10-25 23:02:13' | 28222 |
| 1 | 1 | '2022-10-26 00:42:13' | 28229 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

The 2. query neither works nor is it fast enough at about 14 seconds. It doesn't work because it returns the wrong total production for every timestamp. I hope that you can help me because  I am out of ideas.

Comment: How often does the change in resource production of an owner in a specified game happen?

Comment: Every five minutes about one province changes. One Game is up to 80 days long.

Comment: In this case I would recommend adding date stamps columns for `valid_from` and `valid_until` (basicaly these columns rounded to date); and indexing on them + `game_id`, `owner_id`. Then you would need to reorganize and rebuild your indexes every day (i.e during the time when there're minimal requests happening). Your current indexes are getting outdated every 5 minutes; therefore they're not improving the performance.

Comment: I would at least move the `where a.game_id=1 and a.owner_id = 1` inside the subquery. Currently the query is applying `DISTINCT` against 20940 rows, but it should be doing that against a filtered subset of rows.

Comment: @Dimi I think I have understood what I should do and I am going to try it out later today. But I don’t get why my indexes are getting outdated every 5 minutes.

Comment: @BillKarwin I did what you suggested but the possible speed up wasn’t noticeable.

Comment: @Dimi, MySQL indexes don't get "outdated." They are in sync after every INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. Can you explain more about why you think they need to be rebuilt every day? I don't think that's true.

Comment: @Dimi, thanks for the idea, adding another date column for ```valid_from``` and ```valid_until```. I could reduce the time the query takes down to 10.8s but it isn't fast enough.

Comment: That's a messy looking WHERE.  If it is testing for "overlap" of two ranges, I think there is a simpler expression.

Comment: Check the SUM -- If the results are too high, then be aware that `JOIN` happens before `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Is the `DISTINCT` really needed?  That is, are there any repetitions of those 3 columns?  If not, some significant simplifications can be done.

Comment: @zDox - Did you miss these Comments?

Comment: @RickJames the sum in the first query gives me the right results so everything good there. Yes the distinct is needed because otherwise the query would return the resource production at way too many dates and I only want to calculate the production at dates where it changed.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the two indexes, and adding this one seems to improve performance (When I was able to reproduce a correct set of test-data.... )

The suggested index is:

```sql
CREATE INDEX test_key on province(game_id, owner_id, valid_from, valid_until, resource_production);
```

You can test it by running this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/Yusyr0i4), and look at the times produce by `SHOW PROFILES`.

After running it, comment the `CREATE INDEX` that I am suggesting to use, and uncomment the currently commented indexes (the 2 index you have currently), and re-run the fiddle again, to see the changed times in `SHOW PROFILES`.

This suggested index is covering, because all used fields are contained in the index.

It would be nice to know if, and how much, this improves ...

Comment: I have modfied the [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/LelQW4jm) to better fit my dataset. Every game has about 130k rows and per game one owner owns between 200 and 14k rows of provinces. After i had modfied the test-data with your index query 1 took about 1.28s. With only the index test_valid_from query 1 took 1.12s. The same goes for my real database: test_valid_from index: 17.3s
test_key index: 18.7s

Comment: Please show us what you observed that was useful in `PROFILE`.  (I have never found `PROFILE` to be of any use.)

Comment: @RickJames: I said : ".... to see the changed times in `SHOW PROFILES`", and I do know they are influenced by many things.  But as zDox explained the reproduction of the dataset failed, because with his dataset the change is not positive.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start with moving these into the first 'derived' table:

   ```
    where  a.game_id = 1
      and  a.owner_id = 1
   ```
2. Have this index (as Luuk suggests):

   ```
    INDEX(game_id, owner_id, valid_from, valid_until,  resource_production)
   ```
3. Then see my questions in the Comments above.
4. After that, I may have more advice.

Comment: I did what you suggested but the query still takes about 18.7 seconds. I think the issue is that mysql only uses parts of the index. As in my supplied explain statement 1, it only uses game_id and owner_id from the index.

Comment: @zDox - MySQL uses columns from the left of the index (no skipping).  `=`, then one other thing.  OTOH, "covering" , though less effective, will use any columns in the index.

Comment: I agree with you. You have implied that you may have more ideas after moving the where clause and adding the correct index. Could you please tell them me because I am kinda clueless on what to do next?

Comment: @zDox - Shouldn't you be testing `a.valid_until` in some way?

Comment: @zDox - and...  I see (b.valid_from < a.valid_from) showing up twice; can the expression be simplified?  Also, is this never possible?  b.valid_from > a.valid_from ?

Comment: Well the expression could be reduced to  
" (
     b.valid_from <= a.valid_from 
     and a.valid_from < b.valid_until)
 OR (
     b.valid_until IS NULL
     AND b.valid_from < a.valid_from) "

Comment: @zDox - This might be the same, but not any faster:  `(b.from <= a.from) AND (b.from < a.from OR b.until  IS NULL OR b.until > a.from)`